# What is the difference between generators and templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, code-generation, generator

In Rails we have both generators and templates to quickly setup and configure applications. Superficially, there seems to be 2 differences between generators and templates:

1. You can apply templates when creating a new application with `rails new appname -m path/to/template.rb`. Generators must be run after the creation of a rails app with `rails g generator_name`
2. Generators are classes made up of a series of public methods that are fired in the sequence they are declared. Templates are just a set of commands.

To my mind, this seems to make both generators and templates essentially identical. If I had to choose, I would go with templates because firing a series of public methods in the order they are declared seems to be quite a weird OO abstraction to me. A series of simple commands is far clearer and doesn't require the reader to know that rather unusual convention in order to understand templates.

Are there any more significant differences between generators and templates? If so, are there situations where one is more suitable than another? If not, why does Rails have both and is one method likely to become deprecated at some point?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's mainly a chicken and egg thing that your are describing - the template you are describing (not to be confused with the templates of action view) has to be applied before the app is created, whereas generators do work from within the rails app (and more can be added via plugins etc).   Apples and Oranges.

Comment: You can apply templates to an app after creation with `rake rails:template LOCATION=~/template.rb` as stated [here](http://m.onkey.org/rails-templates). Consequently, templates could also be added by plugins/gems although I have never seen this. There must be some reason for this but I cannot figure out what.